# MVC4 Assigning Date Value to Bootstrap Date Text Box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

This syntax below does not work with MVC4 and the bootstrap date text input.  It works fine with a normal text box.  Please advise, thank you.

```
<input type="date" id="PickupDate" name="PickupDate" class="form-control" value="@Model.PickupDate.ToString("d")">
```

Comment: I am trying to populate the bootstrap date text input box with the date from the database, but nothing appears in the input box with the syntax above.  How to you populate the date text box with the date from sql server dateabase?

Comment: Just fyi, I don't think Bootstrap has a specific date input. What you are seeing is the HTML 5 date input type. See here for more: http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `PickupDate` is a DateTime object, try using this to format it:

```
value="@Model.PickupDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-d")"
```

Also, double check that `@Model.PickUpDate` actually has a valid value.

EDIT:

Try using 2 d's :

```
value="@Model.PickupDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"
```

Comment: @Model.PickUpDate definitely has a date value, if I change the text box back to a normal one it displays the date fine.  But as a bootstrap 3.0 input type="date" class="form-control" I see no way of setting the value property, even if i just try to do something like value="test123" the input date object still comes up empty in the browser.  it's like that object would use some other property rather than value to set it's display value?

Comment: the bootstrap input type="date" class="form-control"  control is fantastic for getting the date from the user on an add new page, but I can't figure out how to display the date back from the database on an edit page with MVC.

Comment: What I am saying is to give the date to the date input in a different format. The date needs to be in a particular format. Here is a CodePen to illustrate what I mean. http://codepen.io/simoncowie/pen/aLKJg

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I believe you are correct.  But, it doesn't work in MVC4.

Comment: both of these work: <input type="text" id="PickupDate" name="PickupDate" class="form-control" value="@Model.PickupDate.ToString("d")">  AND  <input type="text" id="PickupDate" name="PickupDate" class="form-control" value="@Model.PickupDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-d")">   BUT if you change the type to type=date you get nothing in MVC4.   This does not work:    <input type="date" id="PickupDate" name="PickupDate" class="form-control" value="@Model.PickupDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-d")">

Comment: @AustinHarris It works for me in an MVC 4 test project so something else must be going on. What browser are you using? What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Chrome and the new bootstrap 3

Comment: The control just shows the placeholder text "MM/DD/YYYY" no actual date from the database.  Here is what the control looks like when I view sorce:      <input type="date" id="PickupDate" name="PickupDate" class="form-control" value="2013-07-9">   it shows a value, but does not actually display it in the browser.

Comment: Oh, ha. Okay I see the issue. Have added to my answer.